# Add element to a multiple array through a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, registration

I am doing a registry of users using a form and javascript, saving the data that I want to take in variables and through the validate function adding that array of elements that I have defined to a previously created user array (users), but not work

The code is this:

```js
var user = document.getElementById("user");
var pass = document.getElementById("pass");
var enviar = document.getElementById("enviar");
var users = [// user      password  rol
                  ["admin","admin", "1"],
              ];
var prueba;

enviar.addEventListener("click", validar, false);

function validar (e) {
  prueba = [users.value, pass.value, "0"];

    users.push(prueba);


    return users;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>


    <form action="" method="post">
      <h2>Registro de Usuario: </h2>

      <input type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder="Usuario"><br>
      <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Contraseña"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" value="enviar" >
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functionss.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `new Array(user.value+pass.value+"0")` should just be `[user.value, pass.value, "0"]`

Comment: If you using stack snippets provide all the code relevant to your problem. See [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I updated the code with the html. I have edited the code as Olian04 has told me but it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what your problem is but I noticed two things that may break your logic.

On this line you are referring to the list of users but not user input element:

```
prueba = [users.value, pass.value, "0"];
```

When the submit button is clicked your page is refreshed and so your `users` list is recreated.